# Check latest checked radio button?

Tags: html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a huge table of radio buttons, for example, these are their IDs:

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
  b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
```

Row a is selected by default, and each column is grouped together (by name) so that if user selects b3, a3 will become unselected. The problem is that if the user *does* click b3, my jquery code returns a1, because it is the first radio button :checked in my HTML.

**How can I get the latest :checked radio button in chronological order?**

This is my jquery code:

```
 $('#fontPicker input').on('change', function() {
   one = $("#fontPicker input[type='radio']:checked")[0]['id'];
   console.log(one);
 });
```

The only way I can figure it out is to make a function for each group, but that's repetitive and defeats the purpose of coding, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, to group the radios we use the `name` attribute, you can find the selected by group using the [`[name=GROUP]` attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

And you get the group of the clicked `input` using `$(this).attr('name')`.

Also, instead of `input[type='radio']` you can use [`input:radio` selector](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).

See demo below.

```js
$('#fontPicker input').on('change', function() {
   var group = $(this).attr('name');
   var one = $("#fontPicker input:radio[name='"+group+"']:checked")[0]['id'];
   console.log(one);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="fontPicker">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c1" id="a1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c2" id="a2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c3" id="a3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c4" id="a4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c5" id="a5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c6" id="a6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c1" id="b1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c2" id="b2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c3" id="b3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c4" id="b4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c5" id="b5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c6" id="b6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c1" id="c1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c2" id="c2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c3" id="c3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c4" id="c4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c5" id="c5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="c6" id="c6"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Of course, there is a variety of ways you could accomplish the same:

```js
var one = $("#fontPicker input:radio:checked").filter("[name='"+group+"']")[0]['id'];
var one = $("#fontPicker input:radio:checked").filter(function() { return $(this).attr('name') === group; })[0]['id'];
```

But choosing which one is a matter of taste.

Comment: Wow you're my hero! Works like a charm.

Comment: @Rufus You should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers you find useful here